# JQuery not finding element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script with the following (only showing the applicable lines)

```
var setUploadDoneIndicator = function(form)
{
    if ($(form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]').is(':checked') == false)
    {
        console.log("Setting indicator");
        $(form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]').trigger('click');
    }
}

var unsetUploadDoneIndicator = function(form)
{
    if ($(form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]').is(':checked') == true)
    {
        console.log("UnSetting indicator");
        $(form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]').trigger('click');
    }
}

$('[id$=_upload_form]').each(function (event)
{
    current_form = this;

    $(this).fileupload(
    {
        done: function (e, data)
        {
            setUploadDoneIndicator(current_form);
        }
    });
}
```

This ticks a checkbox correctly, the idea is to listen on the checked state of the checkbox on another JS File. If I call unsetUploadDoneIndicator() right after setUploadDoneIndicator() in this script, it unticks the tickbox.

Then in another JS file I have

```
$('#pricing_ab_upload_done_indicator').change(function()
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        console.log("got checked");
        unsetUploadDoneIndicator($('#pricing_ab_upload_form'));
    }
});
```

Which calls the function in the first script, but does not untick the tickbox. I am unsure whether the pointer is passed over correctly, when printing out the received object in unsetUploadDoneIndicator() it does print out a JQuery object which seems correct, the

`if ($(form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]').is(':checked')`

returns true, but the trigger does not happen, so i'm not sure if the element is actually found.

If I change the second script with the following, the trigger to uncheck the box does not happen either

```
$('#pricing_ab_upload_done_indicator').change(function()
    {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            console.log("got checked");
            $('#pricing_ab_upload_done_indicator').trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

Why would the trigger not happen?

Comment: try change current_form = this; to current_form = $(this); - use jQuery this

Comment: where current_form is used everything works fine (the current_form variable is used in other places not shown here as well). The problem specifically comes in when calling the trigger function on the checkbox from the second script, when calling the trigger in the first script everything works correctly

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. Also are `#pricing_ab_upload_done_indicator` and `#pricing_ab_upload_form` unqiue in the DOM ? Do you use any plugin to replace the checkboxes for styling reasons (*if so does it fire the change event on the original checkbox when you click on it*)  ?

Comment: I fear the HTML will be a bit to verbose and will not add value. The two ids are definately unique. Also, the tickbox is found and trigger called successfully in the firtst script (all code and HTML exactly the same, except for the line that references the tickbox ), so I do not think the issue is HTML related

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just remove your functions and use the following:

```
$('[id$=_upload_form]').each(function (event) {
    current_form = this;

    $(this).fileupload( {
        done: function (e, data) {
            var checkbox = $(current_form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]');

            // Set the opposite value
            checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
        }
    });
}
```

Avoid binding multiple events on the same action. I see you have a `.change` event on the checkbox as well, which will result in the `"click"` event triggering twice. This will make it look like nothing happened.

On a sidenote, if you are using the same selector often (like `$(current_form).find('[id$=_upload_done_indicator]')` in your code example), it's better to cache it in a variable to increase performance. It's also easier to work with to write a short variable name instead of repeating the entire selector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first script is for a general upload widget. I need to be able to use it from different pages. When the upload is done, the page using upload widget needs to be notified. I had been informed that the best way of doing this is to tick a hidden tickbox and then listen on the change event from the page that uses the file upload widget. The tickbox needs to be swithed off again after the event has been used. The proposed structure will therefore not work in my case. Also, the change event in the second script only does something if the checkbox state is "checked"

Comment: Why don't you just fire a custom event?

Comment: Could you please post an example or something of how a custom event can be used

Comment: @BOENDAGGER I'm sorry, but no. It's way too extensive to add in comment or answer. If you do some research by yourself I'm sure you can find most of the info you need. If you end up stuck somewhere specific, you can ask for help again here.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Dark Ashelin's advice, I added a custom event. This seems like a much simpler and more logical way of implementing this type of functionality.

In the first script when the upload is done I have

`$(current_form).trigger('event_upload_completed');`

In the second script I have

```
$('#pricing_ab_upload_form').on('event_upload_completed', function()
{
    console.log("Upload completed");
});
```

This way does not require a callback to the first script from the second script to reset the state of the checkbox (it does not require a dummy html element at all)

I tested this in the latest Chrome and FireFox and in IE11. If this method has compatibility issues with older IE's please comment on this answer